# Possible to legally display ads without consent from EU users?

Tags: advertising, gdpr, eu-cookie-law

The EU cookie law, I believe, requires the consent of EU user to place cookies. The ads that I know of on the website uses cookies.

Is possible to legally display ads on website without consent from EU users?

Comment: Yes you can display ads without consent...but only if they don't use cookies.